# how to set a value to the table after user clicks yes button in alert dialog box?

Tags: java, android

this my code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        setContentView(R.layout.manage_account);
        TextView deleteAccount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.delete_account);
        deleteAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        UserMO userMO = dbHelper.getRingeeUserData(1);
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ManageAccount.this);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Deactivate");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Are you really want to deactivate your account?");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //setting isdelete=1 in database
                        userMO.setRingeeUserId(userMO.getRingeeUserId());
                        userMO.setIsDelete(1);
                        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                                return userDelegate.updateUser(userMO, context);

                            }

                        }.execute(null, null, null);


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successfully deactivated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                // Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog.show();
            }

        });

    }
```

i have to set the value for IsDelete=1 when the user clicks yes button  here IsDelete is one of the coloumn in ringee_user table and RingeeUserId is primary key in ringee_user table

when i run above code jboss server shows"updation failed for RingeeUserId=0"